# How to add clickable buttons to Tooltip label in Chakra UI?

Tags: reactjs, button, components, tooltip, chakra-ui

So this is what my component returns. Everything looks great, the buttons and everything looks fine in the Tooltip after I hover over Box showing grade. Just the buttons in the tooltip aren't clickable. Hoverting them doesn't even show the pointer cursor. What can I do about this? Is there an other option/ Maybe other tooltip library with such a support? I don't know but it looks dope, would be nice if it also worked. :)

```
return (
    <Tooltip
      onClick={() => handleDeleteGrade(index)}
      closeDelay={5000}
      openDelay={500}
      label={
        <Flex direction="column" justify="center">
          {" "}
          <Text>Grade: {grade.grade} </Text>{" "}
          <Text>Weight: {grade.weight} </Text>{" "}
          <Text>Comment: {grade.comment ? grade.comment : "-none-"} </Text>{" "}
          <Flex direction="column" gap={3} mt={3}>
            <Button 
             colorScheme="teal" 
             onClick={() => handleEditGrade(index)}>
             Edit
            </Button>
            <Button
              colorScheme="red"
              onClick={() => handleDeleteGrade(index)}
            >
              Delete
            </Button>
          </Flex`your text`>
        </Flex>
      }
      bgColor="#202020"
      hasArrow
      p={15}
    >
      <Box
        _hover={{
          textDecoration: "underline",
        }}
        cursor="pointer"
        key={grade.id}
        p={3}
        borderRadius={2}
      >
        {grade.grade && system.find((g) => g?.grade === grade?.grade)?.name}
      </Box>
    </Tooltip>
  );
```

So to be honest there is nothing I could try more. I'm expecting my buttons to work as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `pointerEvents={"all"}` to Tooltip should fix it! :)

Codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-mccarthy-1oejq9?file=/App.tsx

Comment: that was a tricky one, thanks!

Comment: so i ended up just usign a popover but still thank you sooooo much! good to know for the future, very useful